# Fix tooltips hidden behind sticky position table cells

Tags: css, sticky

I am creating a product features table and it is too wide, so we have made the first column fixed with remaining columns scrolling left/right. My problem is that the tooltips are coming beneath and hidden by the sticky cell in the next row.

Here is the [test table](https://staging.radarsign.com/tooltip-test/)

I have tried everything I can think of with z-index and can't find a way to fix it.

Is this possible or do I need to try something completely different?

Comment: Can you post the pic embeded instead of a link?  I will tell you this though have you considered using Bootstrap to make this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `td` having `position: sticky` is creating its own stacking context in conflict with each other. To make sure that the `td` holding the tooltip will stay on top of the other `td` laying on the row below, set its `z-index` higher.

So, for example, just adding this css rule, will solve the issue:

```
tr.row-14 > td:first-child {
    z-index: 100;
}
```